# Service injection issue with HK2: why doesn't @Inject work despite @Contract on interface and @Service on implementation?

Tags: java, cdi, hk2

I am using the HK2 framework to manage my services, and I have annotated my service interface with @Contract and the service implementation with @Service. However, when I try to inject the service into my code using @Inject, it doesn't work. I receive an error indicating that the service was not found. Why is this happening? Have I missed something in the HK2 configuration or in my code? Thank you in advance for your help.

My dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-metadata-generator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

IUserService:

```java
@Contract
public interface IUserService {
    List<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

UserService:

```java
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        User user1 =new User();
        User user2 =new User();
        User user3 =new User();
        // ... setup users fields
        return List.of(user1, user2, user3);
    }
}
```

UserResource:

```java
public class UserResource {
    @Inject
    private IUserService service;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return service.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

App:

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserResource userResource = new UserResource();
        System.out.println(userResource.getAllUsers());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HK2 isn't magic, and needs to know what your service bindings are.  I highly recommend using the automatic service population as described [here](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/glassfish-hk2/getting-started.html).

You can also manually bind classes or service descriptions into your main, which is difficult to maintain but does the job.

Firstly, add @Service to your UserResources (only hk2 services can inject other hk2 services [there are exceptions]):

```
@Service
public class UserResource {
    @Inject
    private IUserService service;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return service.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

Then fix up your main by getting a ServiceLocator and populating it with your services.  Then get your UserResource FROM hk2 rather than newing it up yourself.  In the end hk2 is a lazy system meaning no service is created without you first asking for a service yourself [again, there are some exceptions to that rule]:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance().create("myServiceLocator");
        
        ServiceLocatorUtilities.addClasses(locator
             , UserService.class
             , UserResource.class);
        
        UserResource myUserResource = locator.getService(UserResource.class);
    }
}
```